# Print title page in header of a specific page

Tags: title, headers, get-the-title

I'm trying to customize Avada template.
I want to print in the header the page title, but only for specific pages.

So I tried in header.php

```
<head>
<?php if ( page_is('80') ) { echo get_the_title($ID);} ?>
</head>
```

but it returns a blank page.
However if I only write

```
<?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?>
```

the page come out correctly.

I can't figure out how to make it work . 
I want the title print in header only for specific pages.
Thanks to anyone who can help me

Answer (score 1):

I was spelling wrong statement.
This worked fine for me

```
<?php if (is_page('80') ) { echo get_the_title();}?>
```

thanks